# How does this URL know I mean my WiFi booster?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I have a Netgear WN1000RP WiFi booster.  You can plug it in the wall, then connect to the booster's wireless network from a machine via the SSID NETGEAR_EXT, then use the URL http://www.mywifiext.net or http://www.mywifiext.com in a browser to reach the booster's configuration page.

Does that mean the booster intercepts and scans every DNS request looking for "mywifiext", and in those cases returns the local IP address of the booster itself?  Or is some other trick used?

Comment: I would guess that you are correct.

Comment: Most likely, it probably monitors HTTP requests going over port 80 and then redirects to the routers configuration page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with the booster you speak of but when you dynamically obtain your IP from the router, you also dynamically obtain your DNS.  And, as luck would have it, the router is your DNS... So it just has "mywifiext.net" in its lookup table like any other DNS entry.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how it works.